# Não é possível converter de decimal para double

Tags: c#, .net, tipagem

A classe abstrata `Figura` possui o método virtual `CalculoArea()`, onde as classes derivadas chamadas de `Quadrado`, `Retangulo` e `Circunferência` sobrescrevem esse método conforme o seu cálculo de figura geométrica, mas encontro o **problema de conversão de decimal para `double` nos métodos `CalculoArea()` da classe `Retangulo` e `Circunferencia`.

Código:

```
using static System.Console;

abstract class Figura
{
    public virtual decimal CalculoArea() => CalculoArea();
}

class Quadrado : Figura
{
    public decimal Lado { get; set; } = 0M;
    public override decimal CalculoArea() => System.Math.Pow(Lado, 4); // Erro de conversão
}

class Triangulo : Figura
{
    public decimal Altura { get; set; }
    public decimal Base { get; set; }
    public override decimal CalculoArea() => Altura * Base / 2;
}

class Circunferencia : Figura
{
    public decimal Raio { get; set; } = 0M;
    public override decimal CalculoArea() => System.Math.PI * System.Math.Pow(Raio,2); // Erro de conversão
}

class Imprimir
{
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Não usar pontos em números decimais e sim vírgulas (Exemplo 7,5 ao invéz de 7.5) 
        Quadrado quadrado = new Quadrado();
        Triangulo triangulo = new Triangulo();
        Circunferencia circulo = new Circunferencia();

        WriteLine("Classe Quadrado");
        Write("Digite o lado do quadrado: ");
        if (!decimal.TryParse(ReadLine(), out decimal digitelado)) return 1;
        quadrado.Lado = digitelado;
        WriteLine();

        WriteLine("Classe Triângulo");
        Write("Digite a altura do triângulo: ");
        if (!decimal.TryParse(ReadLine(), out decimal digitealtura)) return 1;
        triangulo.Altura = digitealtura;
        Write("Digite a base do triângulo: ");
        if (!decimal.TryParse(ReadLine(), out decimal digitebase)) return 1;
        triangulo.Base = digitebase;
        WriteLine();

        WriteLine("Classe Círculo");
        Write("Digite o raio do círculo: ");
        if (!decimal.TryParse(ReadLine(), out decimal digiteraio)) return 1;
        circulo.Raio = digiteraio;
        WriteLine();

        WriteLine($"O cálculo da área do quadrado é {quadrado.CalculoArea()}cm2");
        WriteLine($"O cálculo da área do triângulo é {triangulo.CalculoArea()}cm2");
        WriteLine($"O cálculo da área do círculo é {circulo.CalculoArea()}cm2");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basicamente tem que fazer um *cast* já que o método espera enviar um tipo `double` e retorna este mesmo tipo, sendo que o resultado final está indicando ser `decimal`:

```
using static System.Console;
using static System.Math;

abstract class Figura {
    public virtual decimal CalculoArea() => CalculoArea();
}

class Quadrado : Figura {
    public decimal Lado { get; set; } = 0M;
    public override decimal CalculoArea() => (decimal)Pow((double)Lado, 4);
}

class Triangulo : Figura {
    public decimal Altura { get; set; }
    public decimal Base { get; set; }
    public override decimal CalculoArea() => Altura * Base / 2;
}

class Circunferencia : Figura {
    public decimal Raio { get; set; } = 0M;
    public override decimal CalculoArea() => (decimal)(PI * Pow((double)Raio, 2));
}

class Imprimir {
    static int Main() {
        var quadrado = new Quadrado();
        var triangulo = new Triangulo();
        var circulo = new Circunferencia();
        WriteLine("Classe Quadrado");
        Write("Digite o lado do quadrado: ");
        if (!decimal.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var digitelado)) return 1;
        quadrado.Lado = digitelado;
        WriteLine();
        WriteLine("Classe Triângulo");
        Write("Digite a altura do triângulo: ");
        if (!decimal.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var digitealtura)) return 1;
        triangulo.Altura = digitealtura;
        Write("Digite a base do triângulo: ");
        if (!decimal.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var digitebase)) return 1;
        triangulo.Base = digitebase;
        WriteLine();
        WriteLine("Classe Círculo");
        Write("Digite o raio do círculo: ");
        if (!decimal.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var digiteraio)) return 1;
        circulo.Raio = digiteraio;
        WriteLine();
        WriteLine($"O cálculo da área do quadrado é {quadrado.CalculoArea()}cm2");
        WriteLine($"O cálculo da área do triângulo é {triangulo.CalculoArea()}cm2");
        WriteLine($"O cálculo da área do círculo é {circulo.CalculoArea()}cm2");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/llprk7). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GfqhHP). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Cast/DecimalDouble.cs).

Na verdade, para este tipo de informação o `decimal`provavelmehte é errado e tudo já deveria ser `double`:

```
using static System.Console;
using static System.Math;

abstract class Figura {
    public virtual double CalculoArea() => CalculoArea();
}

class Quadrado : Figura {
    public double Lado { get; set; } = 0;
    public override double CalculoArea() => Pow(Lado, 4);
}

class Triangulo : Figura {
    public double Altura { get; set; }
    public double Base { get; set; }
    public override double CalculoArea() => Altura * Base / 2;
}

class Circunferencia : Figura {
    public double Raio { get; set; } = 0;
    public override double CalculoArea() => PI * Pow(Raio, 2);
}

class Imprimir {
    static int Main() {
        var quadrado = new Quadrado();
        var triangulo = new Triangulo();
        var circulo = new Circunferencia();
        WriteLine("Classe Quadrado");
        Write("Digite o lado do quadrado: ");
        if (!double.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var digitelado)) return 1;
        quadrado.Lado = digitelado;
        WriteLine();
        WriteLine("Classe Triângulo");
        Write("Digite a altura do triângulo: ");
        if (!double.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var digitealtura)) return 1;
        triangulo.Altura = digitealtura;
        Write("Digite a base do triângulo: ");
        if (!double.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var digitebase)) return 1;
        triangulo.Base = digitebase;
        WriteLine();
        WriteLine("Classe Círculo");
        Write("Digite o raio do círculo: ");
        if (!double.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var digiteraio)) return 1;
        circulo.Raio = digiteraio;
        WriteLine();
        WriteLine($"O cálculo da área do quadrado é {quadrado.CalculoArea()}cm2");
        WriteLine($"O cálculo da área do triângulo é {triangulo.CalculoArea()}cm2");
        WriteLine($"O cálculo da área do círculo é {circulo.CalculoArea()}cm2");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/L0IDu1). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nZp4xv). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Typing/Double.cs).

A questão em si pergunta aqui nada tem a ver com polimorfismo, existe isso no código, mas está tudo certo nesta parte.

Comment: Polimorfismo também está presente em códigos que usam `interface`?

Comment: De certa forma sim, principalmente agora que tem implementação em interface, mas o problema desta pergunta nada tem a ver com polimorfismo. Já tem informações sobre o assunto n o site.

Comment: Eu tava com essa dúvida quando em um link que eu vi sobre quando se deve utliizar `interface`